# Add sub folder in area in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an asp.Net MVC application in Which I have definded Areas,

For Example Areas -> Administration

In area I have defined sub folder

For Example in 
Administraion
 -> Controllers -> Folder -> Multiple Controllers
 -> Views -> Folder -> Folder-> View.cshtml

Now my question is this, how to manage routing?

I have updated the routing

```
  context.MapRoute(
                "WorkSpaceManagement_default",
                "WorkSpaceManagement/Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but question is this how to manage view engine so that he can find it view automatically

Comment: Have a look at [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting) - an open source project that enables MVC to use hierarchial folder structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AdministrationAreaRegistration.cs, You can modify the routing as you want.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{

    context.MapRoute(
    "Administration_default",
    "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { area="Administration",controller = "YourController",action = "YourAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```